# SQL subtracting columns

Tags: sql

I have two tables :

flight:

```
ID  maxcapacity
1      10 
2      12
```

Flightbooking:

```
FlightID bookedseats 
1       2
1       3
2       2
```

I want to subtract booked seats from max capacity to give the number of available seats for each flight .

Expected results:

```
FlightID availableseats
1     5
2     10
```

I am new to SQL so any help would be appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation and `join`:

```
select f.id, f.maxcapacity - coalesce(sum(fb.bookedseats), 0) as availableseats
from flights f left join
     flightbooking fb
     on f.id = fb.flightid
group by f.id, f.maxcapacity;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```sql
SELECT      flight.FlightID, 
            flight.maxcapacity - ISNULL(fb.booked, 0) AS availableseats
FROM        flight
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT    FlightID, 
            SUM(bookedseats) AS booked
  FROM      Flightbooking
  GROUP BY  FlightID
) fb 
ON          flight.FlightID = fb.FlightID
```

Pay attention to the `LEFT JOIN` part. If you use `INNER JOIN`, the query won't return flights with no bookings (without records in the `Flightbooking` table).

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT f.ID, f.MaxCapacity - SUM(b.BookedSeates) As AvailableSeats
FROM Flight f
INNER JOIN FlightBooking b on b.FlightID = f.ID
GROUP BY f.ID, f.MaxCapacity
```